# Comprobación por rangos en diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, diccionarios

Estoy realizando un programa de comprobación de puntuaciones para transformarlas de numérico a letras, pero para comprobar los rangos, quiero hacerlo en diccionarios de manera que en vez de hacerlo por sentencias `if`:

```
if numero > 0 and numero < 20:
    resultado = "F"

if numero >= 20 and numero < 50:
    resultado = "D"
```

etc, etc, etc.

hacerlo (si se puede, y aquí viene la duda de cómo hacerlo) en diccionarios, de manera que:

```
resultados = {range(0, 19): "F", range(20, 49): "D", ...}
```

¿Cómo hago yo la comprobación para ver si está en el rango dentro del diccionario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas a necesitar iterar sobre el diccionario y comprobar por cada clave (objeto `range`) si el número está en ella con el operador de pertenencia `in`:

```
numero = 21

resultados = {range(0, 19): "F", range(20, 49): "D"}

for rango, resultado in resultados.items():
    if numero in rango:
        break
else:  # Valor de "resultado" si no se encuentra en ningún rango
    resultado = None

print(f"El resultado es: {resultado})
```

> ```
> El resultado es: F
> ```

El método `dict.items` retorna una vista del diccionario con una tupla `(clave, valor)` por cada pareja clave:valor del diccionario:

> ```
> >>> dict.items()
> dict_items([(range(0, 19), 'F'), (range(20, 49), 'D')])
> ```

Al hacer `for rango, resultado in ...`, en cada iteración desempaquetamos la tupla y asignamos el primer elemento (clave) a la variable `rango` y el segundo elemento a la variable `resultado` (valor).

> ```
> >>> tupla = (7, 23)
> >>> a, b = tupla
> >>> a
> 7
> >>> b
> 23
> ```

Si necesitas realizar la comparación múltiples veces usa un a función, podrás además reutilizarla con diferentes diccionarios:

```
def obtener_valor(diccionario, item, por_defecto=None):
    for rango, resultado in diccionario.items():
        if item in rango:
            return resultado
    return por_defecto
```

---

```
resultados = {range(0, 19): "F", range(20, 49): "D"}
numero = 6
resultado = obtener_valor(resultados, numero)
print(f"El resultado es: {resultado}")
```

> El resultado es: F

```
resultados = {range(0, 3): "F", range(20, 49): "D"}
resultado = obtener_valor(resultados, numero)
print(f"El resultado es: {resultado}")
```

> El resultado es: None

```
resultados = {range(0, 10): "G", range(20, 49): "D"}
resultado = obtener_valor(resultados, numero)
print(f"El resultado es: {resultado}")
```

> El resultado es: G

Se asume que los rangos son excluyentes, si se solapan se retornará como resultado el primero encontrado (que en Python >= 3.6 depende del orden en que fueron  insertados en el diccionario, en versiones anteriores es indeterminado ya que no se mantiene e orden de inserción en un `dict`).

Si existiera solapamiento y quisiéramos todos los valores podemos retorna una lista.

```
def obtener_valor(diccionario, item):
    return [res for rango, res in diccionario.items() if item in rango]

resultados = {range(0, 25): "F", range(20, 49): "D"}
numero = 23
resultado = obtener_valor(resultados, numero)
print(f"El resultado es: {resultado}")
```

> ```
> El resultado es: ['F', 'D']
> ```

Por cierto, en cuanto a tus condicionales iniciales:

- Puedes usar comparaciones encadenadas, es más legible y más eficiente que usar un and.
- Si los condicionales son excluyentes (si un `if` se cumple los otros no lo van a a hacer) no uses `if` encadenados, es ineficiente porque siempre se evalúan todos, usa `if-elif` en su lugar.

---

```
if 0 < numero < 20:
    resultado = "F"

elif 20 <= numero < 50:
    resultado = "D"
```

Por otro lado, tus condicionales iniciales no se corresponden con los rangos, ten en cuenta que el argumento `stop` de `range` no se incluye en el rango y el argumento `start` si:

- `if numero > 0 and numero < 20` -> `range(1, 20)`
- `if numero >= 20 and numero < 50` -> `range(20, 50)`
- `if numero > 60 and numero <= 70` -> `range(59, 71)`
- `if numero >= 80 and numero <= 97` -> `range(80, 98)`

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el valor de rango y resultado en cada iteración? Gracias

Comment: Si, tranquilo, era para que se entendiese el concepto. Gracias por todo, funciona a la perfección.